# memcached error after switching from Java 1.6 to Java 1.7

Tags: java, caching, memcached, distributed-caching

MemcacheD was working fine until we recently switched over to Java 7 from Java 6.  Now we keep getting exceptions such as the following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception waiting for value
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1025)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1042)
...
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cancelled
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:169)
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.GetFuture.get(GetFuture.java:62)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.get(MemcachedClient.java:1021)
```

and this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed waiting for store
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.mutateWithDefault(MemcachedClient.java:1696)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.incr(MemcachedClient.java:1806)
...
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cancelled
    at net.spy.memcached.internal.OperationFuture.get(OperationFuture.java:169)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedClient.mutateWithDefault(MemcachedClient.java:1687)
    ... 75 more
```

thank you are helping!

Comment: +1 also experiencing this issue. Did you file a bug report?